# Why is Scala compiler giving an error on contravariant type

Tags: scala

I get this error:

```
   [error]  found   : zio.ZIO[x.AppEnvironment,Throwable,Unit]
   [error]     (which expands to)  zio.ZIO[zio.clock.Clock with zio.blocking.Blocking with x 
               .ApplicationResources,Throwable,Unit]
   [error]  required: zio.ZIO[zio.clock.Clock with zio.blocking.Blocking,Throwable,Unit]
```

but ZIO is defined as `trait ZIO[-R, +E, +A]`, so  `A with B with C` should be accepted in contravariant position for `A with B`.

Compiled with Scala 2.12.8, sbt 1.2.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so  `A with B with C` should be accepted in contravariant position for `A with B`

No, that would be if the position was **co**variant. Because it's contravariant, `ZIO[A with B with C, ...]` is a **super**type of `ZIO[A with B, <same types>]`, and won't be accepted where that type is expected.